# Can't mock an extension method wtih JustMock

Tags: c#, mocking, justmock

I am trying to mock an extension method with [justmock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JustMock). For some reason it throws the following error:

*"Test method TestProject1.JustMockTest.TestMethod threw exception: 
Telerik.JustMock.Core.ElevatedMockingException: Cannot mock 'TestProject1.Foo'. The profiler must be enabled to mock, arrange or execute the specified target."*

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can´t really mock an extension-method, as those are `static`.

Comment: Hi @HimBromBeere, The thread you have associated is for Moq and I am asking question about a different product - **JustMock**. They claim that JustMock supports  mocking of extension method. Here is the link to their product page where you can check the **Mock Everything** section: https://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx

 Could you please reopen my thread?